# Is this set of vectors a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was asked to tell if the following vectors-set is a basis (vector space not menionted), so after reduction I got the following:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   0 & 1 & 1  \\
   2 & 1 & 3  \\
   { - 1} & 1 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{l}
 x \\ 
 y \\ 
 z \\ 
 \end{array} \right) \Rightarrow \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   { - 1} & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 3 & 3  \\
   0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{l}
 z \\ 
 y + 2z \\ 
 x - \frac{y}{3} - \frac{{2z}}{3} \\ 
 \end{array} \right)$$

So, at this point in order to prove it is not a basis, I need to find $x,y,z$ such that are not linear combination of the three vectors. Right?
How do you that efficiently, just by trial and error?

Comment: The notation is pretty awkward here; a $3 \times 3$-matrix can never equal a $3 \times 1$-vector.

Comment: You right. I wasn't sure how to right it properly using latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the third column vector is the sum of the first two column vectors. Hence, the three column vectors are linearly dependent, so they do not form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

If you didn't notice this, then you can reduce the matrix of column vectors into row echelon form like you did. Because you obtained a row of zeroes, the vectors must be linearly dependent.

Comment: OK, nice one. it's a better approach

Comment: Why "Because you obtained a row of zeroes, the vectors must be linearly dependent" is true?

Comment: @AndrePoole: Do you know the terminology of [row and column ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Main_definitions)? That the vectors are linearly dependent is the same as saying that the column rank is strictly less than $3$. Now, [column rank equals row rank](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/81903/10816), and does not change under elementary row operations. Since the row rank of your reduced matrix is clearly less than $3$, so is the column rank of the matrix you began with.