# Need help proving $n(T)=n(T^*)$ for finite dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In my book this is showed:

> Let H and K be complex Hilbert spaces and let $T\in B(H,K)$. There
>   exists a unique operator $T^* \in B(K,H)$ such that
>
> $(Tx,y)=(x,T^*y)$
>
> for all $x\in H$ and all $y \in K$.

Now this must ofcourse also be the case when $H$ and $K$ are finite dimensional. The book later use in a proof that if both $H$ and $K$ are finite dimensional, then the dimension of the nullspace $\dim(\text{Ker T})=\dim(\text{Ker T}^*)$, that is $n(T)=n(T^*)$. Do you guys have any hints on how to show this?

I was thinking maybe I could create a bijection between the nullspaces, but I am not sure how.

PS: Strictly speaking the book only used it when we had one space H, and both $T,T^*$ was operators on that space, maybe we I have to use that aswell? Then since we have that if $H$ is $k$ dimensional then: $n(T)+r(T)=n(T^*)+r(T^*)=k$, where $r(T)$ denotes the dimension of the image.

Any hints or tips?

Comment: [relevant post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it)

Comment: I like the following argument:
$$
r(T) = r(T^*T) \leq r(T^*)
$$
so that $r(T) = r(T^*)$.  The conclusion follows.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you, so you used that we only have one Hilbert space, not two? But how do you get that $r(T)=r(T^*T)$?

Comment: Did you look at the link in my other comment?

Comment: Yeah, but I wasn't able to generalize from regular matrices to regular vector spaces, but I see you made an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One argument is as follows: we can simply state that
$r(T) \leq r(T^*T) \leq r(T^*)$,
so that $r(T) = r(T^*)$.

To prove that $r(T) \leq r(T^*T)$, it suffices to prove that $n(T^*T) \leq n(T)$.  To prove this, note that
$$
T^*Tx = 0 \implies\\
(x,T^*Tx) = 0 \implies\\
(Tx,Tx) = 0 \implies\\
Tx = 0
$$
so that $\ker(T^*T) \subseteq \ker(T)$.

Comment: Thank you, but you had to implicitely use that we only have one space H, not two, H and K right?

Comment: @user119615 nope, still works with two