# Is $ \operatorname{rank}A =\operatorname{rank} A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, transpose

Assume A is an $m\times n$ matrix with real-valued entries. Is it always true that $\operatorname{rank}  A = \dim \operatorname{Col}  A = \dim\operatorname{Row} A = \dim \operatorname{Col} A^T = \operatorname{rank} A^T$?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it). Maybe some of the [linked questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2315) might be interesting for you, too.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think this question is not quite the same as the more general question in your first link, because here we have the special assumption that $A$ has real-valued entries, which allows us to use the fact that the range of $A^T$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$.  A similar proof can be given in the general case, but we must substitute annihilators for orthogonal complements (this is explained in Lax's linear algebra book, for example) and I think it's not quite as obvious.

Comment: @littleO Well, I did not vote to close, I have just provided links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true, you can prove it using the fact that the range of $A^T$ (denoted here by $\text{Im}(A^T)$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$ (denoted here by $\text{null}(A))$.  This tells us that
\begin{equation}
\text{dim null}(A) + \text{dim Im}(A^T) = n.
\end{equation}

From the rank-nullity theorem, we have:
\begin{equation}
\text{dim null}(A) + \text{dim Im}(A) = n.
\end{equation}

Comparing these two equations, we see that $\text{dim Im}(A) = \text{dim Im}(A^T)$.