# Relationship between intuitionistic logic and infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Tags: logic, reference-request, vector-spaces, intuitionistic-logic

Some time ago, I've heard that there was a relationship between [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) and infinite dimensional vector spaces.

More precisely, the fact that $\neg \neg \phi \to \phi$ may not be "true" in intuitionistic logic could be related to the fact that an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ is not isomorphic to its bidual (see [Erdős-Kaplansky theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61537)), whereas the fact that $\phi \to \neg \neg \phi$ is "true" in intuitionistic logic could be similar to the fact that any vector space $V$ embeds in its bidual.

Does anyone have already heard about this, or could develop this idea (i.e. is it possible to make it more precise)? Is there any reference about it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _Linear logic_ takes this and runs with it. Or do you already know that?

Comment: @Henning Makholm : I've only heard about it, but I'm not sure how to relate it to vector spaces and their duals…

Comment: x @Watson: I must admit I've never worked out the details, and they're not made explicit in any of the material I've read -- but I get a clear sense that something like the category of (finite-dimensional or arbitrary) vector spaces provides a model of (classical or intuitionistic) linear logic, where a proposition corresponds to a vector space, negation corresponds to a dual space, conjunction is tensor product, and disjunction is direct sum.

Comment: If you google for "linear logic banach spaces" you will find some references, e.g., iml.univ-mrs.fr/~girard/banach.ps.gz. I have not looked into these ideas in depth, but the paper by Girard I have just cited seemed to me to give an execution model for linear logic that is inconsistent from the point of view of the Curry-Howard correspondence: the categories involved don't seem to have any empty hom-sets (which means all propositions are provable from the logical point of view). I was probably missing something, so I would be interested to know if I was wrong about this.

Comment: Would this be related (?) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_logic