# Prove that row rank $(A) =$ column rank $ (A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose that $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix then show that row rank $(A) =$ column rank $(A)$.

**My attempt** $:$

Suppose $R$ is the row reduced echelon form of $A$. Then $A$ is row equivalent to $R$ i.e. $R$ can be obtained by applying finite number of row operations on $A$ and the effect of each row operation can be viewed as pre-multiplying $A$ by a suitable elementary matrix. Suppose $R$ is obtained from $A$ by applying $n$ simultaneous row operations and suppose that the corresponding elementary matrices are respectively $E_1,E_2, \cdots , E_n$.Clearly each $E_i$ is a $m \times m$ matrix. Then $R$ can be wriiten as $R =PA$ where $P=E_1E_2 \cdots E_n$ is a $m \times m$ matrix. Since each $E_i$ is invertible so is $P$. Now $R^t=A^tP^t= A^tQ$ where $Q = P^t$. Suppose $Q =(q^1,q^2, \cdots, q^m)$ and $R^t=(r^1,r^2,\cdots,r^m)$. Then by the above equation we get $r^i=A^tq^i$
 for $1 \le i \le m$. i.e. each $r_i$ is in the column space of $A^t$ i.e. in the row space of $A$. So column space of $R^t$ is a subspace of row space of $A$ i.e. row space of $R$ is in the row space of $A$. Again since $P$ is invertible $A=RP^{-1}=RS$ where $S=P^{-1}$. From this equation we similarly have row space of $A$ is a subspace of row space of $R$. Therefore we have row space of $A$ is same as the row space of $R$. Now if  $R$ has $r$ non zero rows then row rank of $R$ is $r$ and cosequently row rank of $A$ is also $r$.

Now if I can show that column rank of $A$ is also $r$ then we are done. But I find difficulty to prove this part. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assume without loss of generality that $m \leq n$. What can you tell me about the leftmost $m \times m$ submatrix of $R$ and what happens to it when you transpose $R$? What does this imply about about the row reduced form of $R^t$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the rank of a matrix the same of its transpose? If yes, how can I prove it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it)

Comment: The link provided by you is good but my question is how can I approach in my way?