# Does $\operatorname{rank} (A^2) = \operatorname{rank} (A)$ for any matrix $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_{n \times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I wanted to prove/disprove whether for every matrix $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_{n \times n}$

> $\operatorname{rank} (A^2) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$ for any matrix $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_{n \times n}$

I know that for two matrices $A, B$ (it actually doesn't matters what is the size of $B$ as long as $AB$ is defined)

$$\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min \{ \operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B)\}$$

Therefore, $$\operatorname{rank}(A^2) \leq \operatorname{rank} (A)$$

In order to prove that:

$$\operatorname{rank}(A^2) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$$

you'd have to prove that:  $$\operatorname{rank}(A^2) \geq  \operatorname{rank}(A)$$ which I don't know how to prove, or finding a different way to prove directly both directions (meaning; one direction is $\leq$ and the other is $\geq$)

Comment: What about nilpotent matrices?

Comment: If $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{m\times n}$ then $A^2$ exists only if $n=m. \qquad$

Comment: In general, for a square matrix $A$, $\text{rank}(A^2)=\text{rank}(A)$ if and only if the column space of $A$ intersects the nullspace of $A$ trivially.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not true that the square of a matrix has the same rank as the matrix itself. For instance, the $2\times 2$ matrix 
$A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$
 has rank $1$ and satisfies $A^2=0$.

Comment: but here's what I'm confused about - for a squared matrix,  $\text rank (A) = \text rank (A^T)$, so 
$\text rank (AA^T) = \text rank (A^2)$

Comment: @Jneven This is a totally separate problem, in general $A^T$ has nothing to do with powers of $A$. I suggest you look at this then: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it

Comment: but $\text rank (A) \leq \text {min}$ {${sp\{R(A)\}}, {sp\{C(A)\}}$

Comment: @Jneven The rank is **not** multiplicative. It is not true that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(A)\operatorname{rank}(B)$ as you seem to suggest. The quantities $\operatorname{rank}(AA^T)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A^2)$ are **not** equal. The matrix $A$ I exhibed in my answer is a counter example for it. I let you compute $AA^T$ and see that it is not zero, whereas $A^2=0$ !

Comment: as my approach for proving this would be:


1. $\text rank(A) = \text rank(A^T)$


2 .this follows that -  $\text rank(A^2) = \text rank(AA^T)$ 

and according to - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n
$ \text rank(AA^T) = \text rank(A^2) = \text rank (A) $

Comment: @Jneven Your point 2. is wrong.

Comment: notice that in the question i wrote: $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min \{ \operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B)\}$

Comment: Yes, and this is true. However, $\operatorname{rank}(AA^T)=\operatorname{rank}(A^2)$ is **not** true. All you can say, using your inequality, is $\operatorname{rank}(AA^T)\leq \operatorname{rank}(A)$ (and also $\operatorname{rank}(A^2)\leq \operatorname{rank}(A)$).

Comment: okay, I get it now. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First, it makes no sense to write $A^2$ if $A$ is not a square matrix. So you need $m=n$.

This being said, there is a class of matrices called **[nilpotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent)**, from which it is trivial to build counterexamples:

$$\operatorname{rk}\left(\matrix{0&1\\0&0}\right)=1$$$$\operatorname{rk}\left(\matrix{0&1\\0&0}\right)^2=0$$

Comment: I would have to disagree about the statement that "it would make no sense". in fact, I think writing $AA$ would just be weird.

Comment: @Jneven No, seriously, it would make no mathematical sense. A product of matrices is defined when the number of columns of the left factor is the number of rows of the right factor.

Comment: you're right, I understood my confusion.