# Rank product of matrix compared to individual matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove $\text{Rank}(AB)\leq \min(\text{Rank}(A), \text{Rank}(B))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48989/how-to-prove-textrankab-leq-min-textranka-textrankb)

> If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times r$ matrix, 
>   prove that the rank of matrix $AB$ is at most $\mathrm{rank}(A)$.

I asked a similar question earlier phrased incorrectly. The above is closer to the actual question generalised.

Comment: A duplicate (actually at least a triplicate!). Handled [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/978/11619) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48989/11619)

Answer (score 36):

$rank(A)$ is the dimension of the column space of $A$. The product $Ab$, where $b$ is any column vector, is a column vector that lies in the column space of $A$. Therefore, all columns of $AB$ must be in the column space of $A$.

Comment: is there any mistake currently in this answer?

Comment: +1 This answer is more understandable than the answers to the duplicate ones

Answer (score 8):

The rank of $AB$ is equal to the dimension of the image of $AB,$ and similarly for the rank of $A.$ The image of $A$ contains the image of $AB.$

Answer (score 8):

$$\mathcal{C}(A) = \{Ax | x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$

$$\mathcal{C}(AB) = \{ABy | y \in \mathbb{R}^r\}$$

Notice how $By$ is an n by 1 vector.

Assume to the contrary that the rank of the latter is strictly greater than the first. Then there exists some $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ that is in $\mathcal{C}(AB)$,  but not $\mathcal{C}(A)$. This implies $\exists z \in \mathbb{R}^r$ such that

$$
ABz = y.
$$

But since $Bz$ is an n by 1 vector, this $y$ will also necessarily lie in $\mathcal{C}(A)$. This is a contradiction.