# A question about invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $5\times5$ matrix that can be written in the form $A=BC$, where $B$ is a $5 \times 4$ matrix and $C$ is a $4 \times5$ matrix. Prove that $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Have you tried anything? A good start might be to see if $A$ has a non-trivial null space....

Comment: @T.Bongers you mean that $Ax=0$ has only solution $x=0$?

Comment: No he means that there is a non zero $x$ such that $Ax=0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the rank inequality for products give us that $rank(A) \leq rank(B)$.

Now, $B$ can have rank $4$ at most- do you see why?

So, $rank(A) < 5$ hence $A$ is not invertible

Comment: what is rank inequality?

Comment: Note that column space of $A$ is contained in column space of $B$. So rank $A \leq rank(B)$

Comment: This will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48989/how-to-prove-textrankab-leq-min-textranka-textrankb