# How to prove $(X^TX)^{-1}$ has rank p where $X \in R^{n \times p}$ and has $Rank(X) = p$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

I was reading Least square solution of Linear Regression. Following is the error function:

\begin{equation}
J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\vert{X\theta-y}\vert}^2
\end{equation}

where $\theta \in R^{p\times1}$, $X \in R^{n \times p}$ and $y \in R^{n \times 1}$

After taking dervative of $J(\theta)$ w.r.t $\theta$ and putting it equal to 0, Following is the valur of $\theta$

\begin{equation}
\theta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
\end{equation}

Now the solution exists when $(X^TX)^{-1}$ exists.

They say if matrix X has rank $p$ (which means features are independent), then $(X^TX)^{-1}$ exists.

Question is:

How can I say $(X^TX)^{-1}$ exist when X has rank $p$??

My attempt:

\begin{equation}
X = \Bigg({\begin{array}{cccc}f_1 & f_2 & f_3 & ...f_p\end{array}}\Bigg)
\end{equation}
where $f_1,f_2,...f_p$ are p features of data matrix $X$ and are linearly independent as X has rank p.

\begin{equation}
(X^TX) = \left({\begin{array}{cccc}{f_1}^Tf_1 & {f_1}^Tf_2 & ... & {f_1}^Tf_p \\ {f_2}^Tf_1 & ... & ....& {f_2}^Tf_p \\ ...& & & \\ ...& ... & ... & {f_p}^Tf_p\end{array}}\right)
\end{equation}

How can I use the fact that $f_1,f_2,..f_p$ are linearly independent to prove that $(X^TX)^{-1}$ has rank $p$.

Comment: You can show that $X^TX$ will always have the same rank as $X$.  There should be a post about this on this site but I'm having trouble finding the link.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/854252/81360)

Comment: $$X^TXy=0\Rightarrow y^TX^TXy=0\Rightarrow \|Xy\|^2=0\Rightarrow Xy=0\Rightarrow y=0.$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks a lot

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks... It's really helpful