# Rank of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that $\text {rank} ( AB)\le \min(\text{rank} B, \text{rank} A) $ and when the equality occurs?
Please help me with this problem by giving hints, solving, or suggesting a book.
Thanks

Comment: Probably a dup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48989/how-to-prove-textrankab-leq-min-textranka-textrankb