# Rank of linear transformations from vector space to same vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a question about a homework question so don't expect a full solution. Just if someone could tell me how I should approach this question. I'm not really sure what kind of manipulation is allowed.

"Let $V$ be a vector space. Show that for every three linear maps $A, B, C : V \rightarrow V$ we have $\operatorname{rk}(ABC)\leq \operatorname{rk}(B)$ "

So all I really know I can say for sure is that if I let $\dim(V)=n$ then $\operatorname{rk}(B)\leq n$ and same for any of the other maps. But no idea how I can compare them and what even $ABC$ is. Is it composition of maps? how can I compare them given such limited info about them?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48989/11619) or for an even earlier version [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/978/11619). Are you having a lightbulb moment? Take your time! No pressure. You are not sitting in an exam now :-)

Comment: And, yes, $ABC$ is certainly the composition. A composition of linear maps is linear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can prove separately that
$$\operatorname{rk}(BC)\le \operatorname{rk}(B)$$
and 
$$\operatorname{rk}(AB)\le \operatorname{rk}(B)$$
and then you combine the two results.

For the first inequality notice that since $C(V)\subset V$ then

$$BC(V)\subset B(V)$$
and then take the dimension. The second inequality is almost similar. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: So been reading up and working on it, thought might be easier to do rk(ABC)≤rk(BC) then rk(BC)≤rkB but fell like I haven't really learned enough about operations on abstract vector spaces to complete this proof. I cant take the dimension as I dont know anything more about A,B or C or V. All I can think is that the domain of ABC is the image of BC but how to get this in proof that follows I dont know. Dont even know how I notate it and make it indisputable that one is not larger than the other.