# Find a matrix A that is diagonalized by matrix P and its transpose to be the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a matrix $P_{M\times N}$ where $M>N$, can I find a matrix $A_{M\times M}$ so that it satisfies this equation?

$P^{T}AP=I$

where $I$ is identity matrix.

Comment: what if P is zero matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two options:

1. $rank(P)<n$:

First of all, we use that $$rank(AB)\leq\min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}$$ As proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48989/how-to-prove-textrankab-leq-min-textranka-textrankb). Then, we have that $$rank(P^TAP)\leq rank(P) < n = rank(I)$$ We have that $rank(P^TAP)\neq rank(I)$ for any choices over $A$, so there is no $A$ matrix that holds the equality.

2. $rank(P)=n$:

If we consider the $QR$ decomposition of $P$ (not full QR), we can write $P=QR$ with $Q\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ such that $Q^TQ=I$ and $R\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ an upper triangular invertible matrix  (because $P$ has full rank). Then, you can choose $A=QR^{-1^T}R^{-1}Q^T$, so: $$P^TAP=(R^TQ^T)(QR^{-1^T}R^{-1}Q^T)(QR) = R^T(Q^TQ)R^{-1^T}R^{-1}(Q^TQ)R $$ $$=(R^TR^{-1^T})(R^{-1}R)=I$$

So we conclude that you can find a matrix $A\in\Bbb R^{m\times m}$ such that $P^TAP=I$ if and only if $P$ is a full rank matrix.

Comment: The identity matrix on the right is $n\times n$ identity. Thus, $rank I = n$.

Comment: Oh you're right.. I'll edit my answer in a few mins. The answer will be "yes" if and only if $rank(P)=n$

Comment: @i707107 Edited with the complete proof.