# How do I prove that the 2 ranks are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **A** be a diagonalizable matrix and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of **A**
$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
Show that $$\rank(\lambda I - A)= \rank((\lambda I - A )^2)$$

Iam not sure whether this is allowed but i tried premultiplying by P and P^{-1} 
such that

$$\rank(P(\lambda I - A)P^{-1})= \rank(\lambda PIP^{-1} -PAP^{-1}) $$

but is this even correct?

Comment: I meant P^-1 as inverse of P i dont know why it didnt format correclty

Comment: You have to write `P^{-1}`.

Comment: Do you know the rank-inequalities of Sylvester? They state that $\text{rank}(AB) \le \min(\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(B))$, which gives one of the two desired inequalities.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik no sorry i havent learn that

Comment: It's easy to prove, though, see i.e [this answer on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48989/how-to-prove-textrankab-leq-min-textranka-textrankb).

Comment: @ViktorGlombik oh so would something like rank((\lambda I - A)(\lambda I - A) <= min(rank((\lambda I - A),rank((\lambda I - A))

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Oh ok sorry when i googled search my question that result didnt appear