# Rank of matrix of linear transformations if we know that $T_1T_2$ is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

For, $n\neq m$,Let $T_1\colon\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ and
$T_2 \colon \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be linear
transformation such that $T_{1}T_{2}$ is bijective then. What is
the rank of $T_1$ and $T_2$?
MY approach: one book says R(T$_{1}$)=R(T$_{2})=m$.another book says R(T$_{1}$)=n and R(T$_{2}$)=m
I beleive former is correct .I just need a verification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank of $ T_1T_2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118692/rank-of-t-1t-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It can be proved that if $T_1 \circ T_2$ is bijective, then $T_1$ is surjective, and $T_2$ is injective. Then using the Rank-Nullity Theorem, what can you conclude?

Comment: T$_{1}$is surjective $\Longrightarrow$$\mathbb{\textrm{R}}$$\left(T\right)$=
$\mathbb{R}$$^{n}$

T$_{2}$is injective $\Longrightarrow$N$\left(T\right)$=0 $\Longrightarrow0$
+ R$\left(T\right)$=Dim$\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$

rank of T$_{1}$=n

rank of T$_{2}$=m