# Proof of when $C=AB$ not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I've got the following excercise in my textbook:

> Prove that if $ A$ is an  $m \times  n$  matrix,  $B$ is an $n \times  m$  matrix and $ n 
> < m$, then $AB$  is not invertible.

to which I need to construct a proof only using the concepts of *row-equivalence* and *matrix multiplication* (no vector theory, rank etc).

**My Proof #1**:
Let $Bx=0$ be a system of $n$ linear equations in $m$ unknowns.

We know that

- if $n<m$, then the system has non-trivial solution. Therefore, the system $ABx=0$ also has non-trivial solution (i.e a $p$-parameter family of solutions, non unique).
- if $AB$ is row-equivalent to $I$, then the system $ABx=0$ has only the trivial solution (i.e $x=0$) and vice-versa.

Since $ABx=0$ is shown to have non-trivial solution, $AB$ is not row equivalent to $I$. Hence $AB$ does not have an inverse.

**My proof #2**:
Consider the matrix $A$. Since $m>n$, the row reduced echelon form of $A$ would have atleast one row of zeroes. Therefore $AB$ would also have atleast one row of zeroes which isn't row equivalent to the identity matrix and hence not invertible.

Is this good?

Comment: Compare with the usual proofs, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383847/if-a-is-an-m-times-n-matrix-b-is-an-n-times-m-matrix-and-nm-then-a).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I already did. The arguments there are not equivalent to mine (or may be they are but I don't realize). I'm pretty confident in my proof but just needed a confirmation.

Comment: And I am pretty sure that you can confirm this yourself. I think you only need to be more exact. If you say $ABx=0$ "has trivial solution" you probably mean "has *only* the trivial solution. And so on.

Comment: @DietrichBurde understood

Comment: Seems not changed yet:" then the system $ABx=0$ has trivial solution (i.e $x=0$) ". But this is always true, without $AB$ being row-equivalent to $I$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that is a theorem which I just read (and understood) which states "$Ax=0$ has trivial solution only if and only if $A$ is row-equivalent to $I$ (of same order)"

Comment: @DietrichBurde gotcha. Fixed that.