# Assume $A$ is symmetrical. Prove that $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is non-singular if, and only if, $BA B^T$ is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea how to even approach this problem. I am not necessarily wanting the whole solution but can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: All you need is the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), the [rank property](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope) and the fact that for a non-singular matrix $B$ we have $y=Bx\ne 0$ iff $x\ne 0$.

Comment: Brilliant! The fact that you reminded me that $Bx \neq 0$ if $x \neq 0 $ is a property of a non-singular matrix B, nudged me in the right direction. Additionally, if a matrix $C$ is non-singular then $C^T$ is also non-singular and vice-versa. These are the things needed to solve this proof.