# Prove that an mxn matrix with m<n has no left inverse, similarly an mxn martix with m>n has no right inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

I wonder how can I prove

> A matrix $A_(mxn)$ with $m \lt n$ has no left inverse 
>   and a matrix $A_(mxn)$ with $m \gt n$ has no right inverse

Because I got no idea about that

Comment: Do you know a theorem about the rank of a product of matrices?

Comment: Hello, Onur. Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post about how to ask for help with homework. Also, excellent advice on how to ask a good question in general can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960).

Comment: It is also worth mentioning for typesetting, `X_lotsofstuff` displays as $X_lotsofstuff$ whereas `X_{lotsofstuff}` displays as $X_{lotsofstuff}$.  If you have more than one character in a subscript or superscript, enclose it in braces.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- $rank(A_{m\times n})\leq \min(m,n)$

Immediate from interpretation of rank as number of pivots in RREF form of matrix

- $rank(AB)\leq \min(rank(A),rank(B))$

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope)

- $rank(I_{n\times n})=n$

Immediate from interpretation of rank as number of pivots in RREF form of matrix

> Further hint, if it so happened that $A$ has a left inverse, $B$, and $m<n$, in other words $BA=I$, what shape is $BA$?  How many rows, how many columns?  What is the rank of $A$?  What is the rank of $I$?