# Query about another post $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

For, $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B))$

On this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope) I don't understand why it is enough to prove $\dim \operatorname{range}(AB)\leq \dim R(A)$ and  $\operatorname{range}(AB)\leq \dim R(B)$. Wouldn't the "min" part play a role as well?

Comment: You don't need \operatorname{min}; you can just write \min.  And in a "displayed", as opposed to "inline", context, that effects positioning of subscripts, thus: $$ \min_{x\in\mathcal X} f(x) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving both $a\le b$ and $a\le c$ is the same as proving $a\le\min\{b,c\}$.

Comment: Thanks. That is good to know.