# $A$ and $B$ are two $4\times4$ matrices such that $AB=0$. Why is $\operatorname{rank}(BA)<3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given two $4 \times 4$ matrices $A$ and $B$. Prove that if $AB=0$ then $\operatorname{rank}(BA)<3$, i.e. $\operatorname{rank}(BA)$ is $2$ or less.

Now, i can definitely see the reason behind the conclusion, i tried many things to do in order to simplify AB its just too hard, so i tried to simplify the question.

If $AB = 0$ then $BA$ will have at least 2 zero rows.

From there i tried to get into conclusion that both matrixes must have at least 2 sets of 2 rows that they are must be similar (1 is multiplicity of the other) and its was a very long deduction.

I am a little hopeless and need help, thanks.

Comment: What is p(BA) supposed to represent?  The rank of $BA$?

Comment: What do you mean by $p(BA)$?

Comment: its rank, and thank u JMoravitz !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that by $p(BA)$ you mean $rank(BA)$ we approach by contradiction

Suppose that $rank(BA)\geq 3$

Since [$rank(BA)\leq \min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope) this implies that both $rank(A)$ and $rank(B)\geq 3$ further implying $nullity(A)\leq 1$ and $nullity(B)\leq 1$

Now, this would imply that as $rank(B)\geq 3$ there are at least three linearly independent nonzero outputs of $Bx$, at most one of which can be in the kernel of $A$, implying the remaining two are not in the kernel of $A$.  By using one of those vectors which maps to the image of $B$ which is not in the kernel of $A$ we show that there exists a vector $x$ such that $ABx\neq 0$ hence $AB\neq 0$.

By contradiction then, if $AB=0$ then $rank(BA)<3$

Answer (score 2):

Another simple proof.

$(BA)^2 = B(AB)A = 0$ => Im(BA) is subset of Ker(BA) => $dim(Im(BA)) \le dim(Ker(BA))$=> $2dim(Im(BA)) \le 4$ => $dim(Im(BA)) \le 2$