# Given $n \times n$ matrices, $A$ and $B$, show that ${\rm rank}(AB) \leq {\rm rank}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-rank

I don't know if I'm missing something out but is this just not proved by saying ${\rm Im} (AB)$ subspace of ${\rm Im}(A)$ so ${\rm rank}(AB) \leq {\rm rank}(A)$?

Comment: It is, except you should replace in the proof $A$ and $B$ with the associated linear maps (after a basis  has been chosen).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope) post, this question was already asked.

Comment: @Bernard Would this result be different if, say, $A$ and $B$ were not $n \times n$ matrices (but still defined such that their product made sense)?

Comment: @BBC3 Okay, but what is it about these being $n \times n$ that allows you to say it is specifically less than $rank(A)$ rather than $\text{min} \{ rank(A), rank(B) \}$

Comment: It would be exactly the same.

Comment: BBC3 cannot reply to your comment because s/he doesn't have enough reputation to leave comments.  His/her comment above was posted as an answer then converted into a comment.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26391/18398

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove, by definition of "minimum," $\min(a,b)\le a$ no matter what the setting is.

Comment: Got it now - cheers!