# Rows linearly independent implies columns linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If you have an $m \times n$ matrix and the rows are linearly independent, are the columns linearly independent too?

I know that it's the case for $n \times n$ matrices.

I've yet tried to think about it, and I think the answer is yes, for example the matrix: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ a & 2a & 3c \end{bmatrix}$ has linearly dependent rows and columns, but I'm not sure that it works for every $m \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Say you have $m$ rows and $n$ columns with $n>m.$  You can never have $n$ linearly independent $m$-dimensional vectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove and interpret $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \operatorname{min}(\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take

$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 &0 \\2 &0 &1\end{pmatrix}$

then the rows are linear independent, but the columns aren't, since for example for the first column you have$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

> If you have an m x n matrix and the rows are linearly independent, are the columns linearly independent too?

This is only necessarily true when the matrix is square.

Answer (score 2):

In $m\times n$ matrix, the maximum number of independent rows or columns possible is the order of the largest square you can get from it. If $m >n$ then order of the largest square is n, so you can get at most n linearly independent rows or columns (and vice versa). If you get x linearly independent rows then you will also get same number of linearly independent columns also (and vice versa), even for a rectangular matrix.

Answer (score 1):

- Your set of vectors that form the matrix are linearly independent, iff your matrix is invertible.
- only square matrices are invertible.
- Therefore, only square matrices are linearly Independent.

Comment: This is not necessarily a good reasoning. Set that forms a matrix can be linearly independent even in rectangular matrices. The first point is wrong.