# $\mathrm{rank} (AB)\leq \min\{\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(B)\}$

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-rank

How do I start proving this? I don't really know where to start.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove and interpret $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \operatorname{min}(\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope)