# If the columns of AB are linearly independent, how can I prove the columns of B must be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, independence

So a matrix, A, is linearly independent if A**x** = **0** has only the trivial solution (**x**=**0**)

so let A = AB, then if the columns of AB are linearly independent, the equation (AB)**x** = **0** has only the trivial solution

by the associative law of multiplication, (AB)C = A(BC), so (AB)**x** = A(B**x**) = **0**

I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if this is a proper way to go about proving that the columns of B are linearly independent

Comment: Also [this oldie with several quality answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978/11619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Bx=0$ has a nonzero solution $x$, then it also solves $ABx=0$.

Comment: ohhh, that makes sense. So if B is linearly dependent, x can be a non-zero vector and ABx=0 would have a non-trivial solution (which can't be the case if the columns of AB are linearly independent). So B's columns must be linearly independent. Thank you for the help!