# Can $AB$ be invertible if $A\in \mathbb R^{3\times 2}$ and $B\in \mathbb R^{2\times 3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I saw this question in practice problems and have seen similar questions asked about this on here. I proof that I'm not sure if it's acceptable or not:

It is known that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$ 
So we have $(XY)^{-1} = Y^{-1}X^{-1}$
but as $X$ and $Y$ are non-square matrices, the right-hand side doesn't exist and therefore the left-hand side doesn't either.

Comment: What do $X$ and $Y$ have to with $A$ and $B$? You should put the actual problem in the body of the question too.

Comment: Try to be more detailed with the first statement you make. What is $A$ and $B$ in that statement?

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 4):

Even simpler: You can also think of it in terms of linear maps, without using the rank inequality.

If $B\in \mathbb R^{2 \times 3}$ then $B$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ which can not be injective, by dimensionality reasons. Hence $AB=A\circ B$ is not injective and therefore not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

By your logic, the matrix $[1]$ is not invertible, since $[1]$ is the product of the matrix $[1, 0]$ with the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

The statement you are trying to use is:

> If $A$ and $B$ are inverible square matrices, then $C=A\cdot B$ is
> invertible, and $C^{-1} = B^{-1}\cdot A^{-1}$.

However, from the fact above, it does **not** follow that if $A$ and $B$ are nonsquare, then their product is not invertible. If $A$ and $B$ are non-square, then the above fact says **absolutely nothing** about their product. In fact, as my example shows, a product of two non-square matrices absolutely **can** be invertible.

---

However, in your case, the simplest way to think about your problem is using the rank of matrices. In particular, the rank of a product of matrices is **at most** the rank of either matrix (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope) for details).

Given that, you can answer the following questions:

- What is the largest possible rank of $X$?
- What is the largest possible rank of $Y$?
- Therefore, what is the largest possible rank for $XY$?
- What is the size of the matrix $XY$?

Comment: I see, thank you

Answer (score 0):

By thinking in terms of rank, we have first that ${\rm rank} A B \le {\rm rank} B$, true for any matrices $A, B$. Since the maximum possible value of ${\rm rank} B$ is $2$, then we have ${\rm rank} A B \le 2$. So, $A B$ as a matrix representing a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be surjective, and hence cannot be bijective.